# How do you get to the tower in Chaper 12 ("Abducted") of Uncharted 3?

Tags: uncharted-3

In the Abducted chapter (the shipyard area) you get to a big area of water surrounded by large ships and containing a few small boats. I killed all the enemies but have circled the area many times and can't figure out where to go next. Where am I supposed to go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Head towards the far right corner by the mounted gun.

[image: Ladder on mast]

You can climb up the ship to the side of the mounted gun, look to climb a ladder up the ship's mast.

[image: Climb up the mast]

You will have to take out some bad guys and can then make your way backwards over the wall.

Comment: Was going to answer my own question (as I did finally figure it out) but got called away after I asked it!

Comment: I'll add some screenshots that I had already put together.